# Can't get the data I want on Python

Tags: python, json, twitter

I'm Python user with Spyder. I want to convert the data(tweets) from notepad, and put out the converted data to other notepad. Its code is like that. It will make simple data such as `{created at: date, user_name, unicode..} -> user_name, data`

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json

tweets_filename = 'C:/Users/siri_0.txt' #unconverted data
tweets_file = open(tweets_filename, "r")

for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line.strip())
        if 'text' in tweet: 
            print (tweet['id']) 
            print (tweet['created_at']) 
            print (tweet['text']) 
            print (tweet['user']['id']) 
            print (tweet['user']['name']) 
            print (tweet['user']['screen_name']) 
            hashtags = []
            for hashtag in tweet['entities']['hashtags']:
                hashtags.append(hashtag['text'])
            print(hashtags)

            output = "C:/Users/fn_siri.txt"
            #I want to put the converted data here.
            out_file = open(output, 'a')
            out_file.write(line)
            out_file.close()

    except:
        continue
```

Unfortunately, `C:/Users/fn_siri.txt` can contain only 'unconverted data'. How can I change the code for containing the converted data?

Comment: You are iterating over all `line` in `tweets_file`, then do a lot of `print`ing and then store the original `line` value into your output-file. Intstead of printing your information to screen, you should store them as text-strings in variables and save those to file. Is that where you need help?

Comment: I solved it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing out `line` to your output file, which is your unconverted input, rather than writing only the data you want.

So, if you want to write out the username, followed by a comma, followed by e.g. the text, you need to replace your `out_file.write(line)` with:

`out_file.write(tweet['user']['name'] + "," + tweet['text'] + "\n")`

You need the `\n` at the end to make sure it has a new line after every line of data

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json

tweets_filename = 'C:/Users/siri_0.txt' #unconverted data
tweets_file = open(tweets_filename, "r")
for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line.strip())
        out_file = open(output, 'a')
        if 'text' in tweet: 
            print (tweet['id'],) 
            print (tweet['created_at']) 
            print (tweet['text']) 
            print (tweet['user']['id']) 
            print (tweet['user']['name']) 
            print (tweet['user']['screen_name']) 
            hashtags = []
            for hashtag in tweet['entities']['hashtags']:
                hashtags.append(hashtag['text'])
            output = "C:/Users/fn_siri.txt"
            print(hashtags,file=out_file)
            #I am assuming the converted data you want to write to out_file is hashtags
            #out_file.write(line)# why are you writing old data here ...
            out_file.close()
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :D